# Visual Studio Code source control might be deleting all my computer files

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am very new to coding and was trying to figure out how to use git. I downloaded the git extension on VS Code and was using the built in terminal and navigated to 'git init -> git add ' to practice pushing files/projects into GitHub.

Every single file on my computer is now gone and this is what is showing up on vscode -> source control [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quas1.jpg). Can anyone please tell me what this means and if it's possible to recover my files back?

Comment: you have created a git repo in your home directory, do do this, call `git init` in a subdirectory/project-directory, or you forgot to set a `.gitignore` file to ignore the `node_modules` directory

Comment: could you please explain what steps i need to make to retrieve my files back?

Comment: Have you tried opening the folder in Finder? The screenshot doesn't show any lost files, it shows that git (not VS Code) considers the existing files to be changes to the repository. If every file was gone you wouldn't be able to boot much less run VS Code.

Comment: all my folders and subfolders are showing but no files in any of them @PanagiotisKanavos